# MysqI_fetch_array and calling data using varibles

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently messing around with a web based ticker style game that i want to make, i go back to it every now and again.

Currently im stuck, i have the need for a `mysql_fetch_array` to pull some data out however i want the table name to be a varible.

So basicly i have this.

```
startplay();

while ($Scount = mysql_fetch_array($playcount))
{
$splaycount = $Scount['$wnu'];
}
```

`$wnu` is pulled out of another array and is a changing number which match's the datafields in the `mysql` database.

So in short is there a way to make `$wnu` work as a varible? as currently i think its trying to find one called `$wnu`, instead of `w1` (which is what the varible contains)

Comment: stop using `mysql_*` functions. use PDO or MySQLi instead

Comment: string with single quotes will not be parsed by PHP

Comment: Yup aware i should be using the newer PDO or MySQLI and it is something i need to change about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($Scount = mysql_fetch_array($playcount))
{
    $wnu = $otherArray[0];
    // If $wnu is not a String then change it to one
    $wnu = "".$wnu;
    // or
    $wnu = "$wnu";

    $splaycount = $Scount[$wnu];
}
```

Comment: That did the job, everything i read said about not being able to get rid of the single quotes, so its the only thing i never tried , thanks a bunch